# Shall i proceed with CEH-LPT-OSCP? Or any other course?

Tags: network, secure-coding

Well actually i am student and will be completing my school in more 2-3 months.
Being really interested and keen towards the cyber security,  i have really surfed the net and asked friends and seniors to ask how shall i proceed. 
If someone could tell me , if i want to set in this field , what are the best course of options that i should do, would be a great help.
On internet its really a mess about CEH / LPT / OSCP / ECPPT etc.
Currently i only know C++ and SQL. 
Wanted to know that how STEPWISE should i proceed with these courses to get settled in this field.

Thanks.  :)

Comment: You will find certain courses require commercial experience, I believe the CEH is one and needs 2 years and / or an employer sponsored course. OSCP is not an easy cert and again needs real expetience. When you finish your education, maybe look for entry level security jobs and use this to build skills. Certification is a good goal but there's no rush.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also currently a student close to graduating, my degree is in MIS and I have had a concentration in information security. Before even attending my 4 year I had spent a bit of time doing research on infosec and pentesting. One thing I will say is these are two similar but different fields, but both provide very valuable info. My suggestion is to read these two books, The first one is what I read before coming to 4 year. The basic of pen testing will teach you red team tools, networks, website security, and how to use the command line. The second book follows the curriculum of my information security and assurance course; this is typically understanding what a vulnerability is, CIA triad, least user privilege..ect. Infosec is more business side with analytics; where as pen-testing is more the infield computer engineering position. As for certs CEH is good to have, so is security+ people might disagree, but they are slightly easier and just having the certs show you are willing to learn more about the field.

I have no real world job experience, but the people I have talked with about corporate security say the positions will be looking to see that you understand security controls, understand what an audit is, know how networks work, and some red team tools. Each opportunity is different I personally try to have a grasp on everything, but focus on networks as that is what drives most internet and corporate information. I hope this helps I am sure more people will chime in, good luck with your research.

[https://www.amazon.com/Basics-Hacking-Penetration-Testing-Second/dp/0124116442/ref=sr_1_7?ie=UTF8&qid=1487705873&sr=8-7&keywords=pentesting](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0124116442)

[https://www.amazon.com/Basics-Information-Security-Second-Understanding/dp/0128007443/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1487705896&sr=8-4&keywords=information+security](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0128007443)

Comment: thanks for your reply...  i too hope more people come in here and help us  It will also be great if you could tell exactly right from the start to the end,  what courses to opt for?